# Error When Executing Gulp on Mac OS X

Tags: gulp

Having trouble running Gulp, and not quite sure what the issue is here. I've Googled the error, yet all forums that have come up haven't fixed my issue.

Here's the relevant install info:

```
npm -v
2.11.3
node -v
v0.12.7
node -p process.versions
{ http_parser: '2.3',
  node: '0.12.7',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '14',
  openssl: '1.0.1p' }
node -p process.platform
darwin
node -p process.arch
x64
```

And the error I'm getting when executing Gulp:

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found in /PATH/TO/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (/PATH/TO/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:148:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/TO/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:16:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/TO/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:163:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Kind of lost on what to do next...

Comment: Maybe install libsass?

Comment: Yeah lol. Installed it, yet it's still throwing the error.

Comment: Did you try installing [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). The error info states that you should reinstall node-sass and I don't see that you checked what version of node-sass you have installed either, so I'm thinking you may have not installed node-sass.

Comment: I tried both. I'll run npm install node-sass again though. UPDATE: Installed again "sudo" yet still giving that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `npm rebuild node-sass` after `npm install node-sass`.

Comment: After I deleted almost every local dependency, this worked. Not sure what was going on. Maybe a random hiccup.